# Using Apply over multi-dimensional table

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following two codes. The first one

```
Table[Total[DeleteDuplicates[{p[i1], p[i2]}]], {i1, 2}, {i2, 2}]
```

works:

> {{p[1], p[1] + p[2]}, {p[1] + p[2], p[2]}}

but the second one

```
Table @@ {Total[DeleteDuplicates[{p[i1], p[i2]}]], {i1, 2}, {i2, 2}}
```

does not:

> {{2 p[1], p[1] + p[2]}, {p[1] + p[2], 2 p[2]}}

However, I want to construct this table in $m$-dimensional case, which means

```
t[n_, m_] := Table @@ {Total[DeleteDuplicates[Table[p[i[j]], {j, m}]]], Sequence @@ Table[{i[j], n}, {j, m}]}
```

and then it outputs the incorrect result as the second one above. I cannot use

```
t[n_, m_] := Table[Total[DeleteDuplicates[Table[p[i[j]], {j, m}]]], Sequence @@ Table[{i[j], n}, {j, m}]]
```

because it will cause a compile error:

```
t[4, 3]
```

> Table: Iterator {Sequence[{i[1],4},{i[2],4},{i[3],4}]} does not have appropriate bounds.

How could I deal with it?

Comment: For the second one, it doesn't work, because the `DeleteDuplicates` isn't carried over (i.e. `{Total[DeleteDuplicates[{p[i1], p[i2]}]], {i1, 2}, {i2, 2}}` evaluates first to `{p[i1] + p[i2], {i1, 2}, {i2, 2}}` before `Table` acts. To get the last version to work, do `Sequence @@ Table[{i[j], n}, {j, m}] // Evaluate` instead of just `Sequence @@ Table[{i[j], n}, {j, m}]`.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're after?

```
n = 5
ps = Array[p, n]
Total /@ DeleteDuplicates /@ Tuples[ps, n]
```

Answer (score 2):

Alan already gave a nice alternative using `Tuples`, but perhaps closer to the original formulation:

```
Array[Total[DeleteDuplicates[p /@ {##}]] &, {2, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{p[1], p[1] + p[2]}, {p[1] + p[2], p[2]}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**Re: *`t[n_, m_] := Table @@ {...}`  outputs the incorrect result*:**

You need to pass the first element in your list `{Total[...], Sequence@@...}`  to `Table`  as `Unevaluated` so that `DeleteDuplicates` gets to work after iterator values are injected:

```
ClearAll[t]
t[n_, m_] := Table @@ {Unevaluated@Total[DeleteDuplicates[Table[p[i[j]], {j, m}]]], 
      Sequence @@ Table[{i[j], n}, {j, m}]}

t[2, 2]
```

> {{p[1], p[1] + p[2]}, {p[1] + p[2], p[2]}}

```
t[3, 2]
```

> {{p[1], p[1] + p[2], p[1] + p[3]}, {p[1] + p[2], p[2], p[2] + p[3]},
>      {p[1] + p[3], p[2] + p[3], p[3]}}

```
t[2, 3]
```

> {{{p[1], p[1] + p[2]}, {p[1] + p[2], p[1] + p[2]}},
>      {{p[1] + p[2], p[1] + p[2]}, {p[1] + p[2], p[2]}}}

**Re: *I cannot use `t[n_, m_] := Table[..]` because it will cause a compile error***

You can wrap `Sequence@@...` with `Evaluate`:

```
ClearAll[t2]
t2[n_, m_] := Table[Total[DeleteDuplicates[Table[p[i[j]], {j, m}]]], 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{i[j], n}, {j, m}]]      ]
t2[2, 2]
```

> {{p[1], p[1] + p[2]}, {p[1] + p[2], p[2]}}

**Note:** Cleanest way is defining your `t[n_,m_]` using `Array` as in Mr.Wizard and Alan's answers:

```
ClearAll[t0]
t0[n_, m_] := Array[Total[DeleteDuplicates[p /@ {##}]] &, ConstantArray[n, m]]

t0[3, 2]
```

> {{p[1], p[1] + p[2], p[1] + p[3]}, {p[1] + p[2], p[2], p[2] + p[3]},
>      {p[1] + p[3], p[2] + p[3], p[3]}}

Comment: Forgive me but I think this unnecessarily baroque, and I updated my answer with a competing recommendation if this sort of thing is desired.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, somehow I could not get the version with `Unevaluated` work when I first tried. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** for higher dimensions.

You may use [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html).

It seems that you just want to do an outer-product but with a special function instead of [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html). This function should have the characteristics of `f` defined below.

With

```
ClearAll[f]
f[s : Repeated[a_, ∞]] := a
f[OrderlessPatternSequence[a_, a_, b__]] := f[a, b]
f[b__] := Total[{b}]
```

`f` is [overloaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) with three signatures.  Note that `f` takes an arbitrary number of parameters.

1. The first is when all parameters are equal then return the parameter.
2. The second removes duplicates from the parameters. Here, `f @@ DeleteDuplicates[{a, b}]` could be used instead of `f[a, b]` to short-circuit recursive calls.
3. The third gives the sum of the terms; which will all be unique after passing through the definition above.

---

Actually, `f` can be simplified to,

```
ClearAll[f]
f[b__] := Total@DeleteDuplicates@{b}
```

Which makes `t` below noticeably faster. Perhaps the fastest posted thus far.

---

And

```
ClearAll[t, p];
t[dims__Integer?Positive] := Outer[f, Sequence @@ Map[p, Range /@ {dims}, {2}]]
```

`t` performs a generalised outer-product over the dimensions using `f` instead of `Times`; an outer-*f*.  Note that `t` also takes an arbitrary number of parameters.

Then

```
t[2, 2]
% // MatrixForm
```

> ```
> {{p[1], p[1] + p[2]}, {p[1] + p[2], p[2]}}
> ```
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
t[2, 3]
% // MatrixForm
```

> ```
> {{p[1], p[1] + p[2], p[1] + p[3]}, {p[1] + p[2], p[2], p[2] + p[3]}}
> ```
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

And higher dimensions

```
t[3, 3, 3];
% // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
t[2, 3, 2, 4];
% // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

And so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would you generalize this to larger examples?  I mean like `Array[Total[DeleteDuplicates[p /@ {##}]] &, {2, 3, 2, 4}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard See update

Comment: Actually, I could speed things up by changing `f` to `ClearAll[f]; f[b__] := Total@DeleteDuplicates@{b}`. Then I think this would be a contender to be one of the fastest here.